# Billdesk payment gatwayintegration with php website

Tags: web-services, post, postman, payment-gateway

i got the following error

Sorry we are uable to process your request right now - Invalid merchant details (ERRP004).

where is the problem

Comment: Which payment gateway are you using?

Comment: I am getting same error.

Comment: I am getting same error !!!

Comment: Please can any one give me solution to this error